# Python: Detect Android

Tags: android, python, operating-system, detect

I'm surprised to find very little info on this topic. I want to detect if a user is running Android. I'm using:

```
platform.dist()
```

This perfectly detects all all OSs and different Linux distros. However, when running this on Android, it system name is always returned as "Linux". Is there any way to detect Android? I do not want to include any 3rd party modules, since this has to be as portable as possible. Is there maybe some specific Android function that I can call in a try-catch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with [Kivy](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.utils.html#kivy.utils.platform)

```
from kivy.utils import platform

if platform == 'android':
    # do something
```

EDIT:

> As I said, I cannot use any 3rd party libs

[Take a look at how Kivy implemented it](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/4c6f7be66628e01a22e3bd72b19db2380a6444bb/kivy/utils.py#L416).

```
def _get_platform():
    # On Android sys.platform returns 'linux2', so prefer to check the
    # presence of python-for-android environment variables (ANDROID_ARGUMENT
    # or ANDROID_PRIVATE).
    if 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT' in environ:
        return 'android'
```

Comment: As I said, I cannot use any 3rd party libs. The program has to be portable and can only use the standard python modules.

Comment: There be an implied `from os import environ`... to those that want the whole answer without another clicked link.

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.7, you can check for the existence of `sys.getandroidapilevel()`:

```py
import sys

if hasattr(sys, 'getandroidapilevel'):
    # Yes, this is Android
else:
    # No, some other OS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import environ
if 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO' in environ:
   print("Android!")
else:
   print("!Android")
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

System name is returned 'Linux' because Android is also based on the Linux Kernel.Android is the name of the distro but deep down its linux.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But I still want to know if the device is Android or not, so that I can distinguish between Android and other distros. All other distro's names are returned (eg: Ubuntu, Fedora, etc), but not for Android

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy you can do it without kivy or with kivy module using hpcomt module

```
import hpcomt
os_name = hpcomt.Name()
print(os_name)

# Output
# Android
```

Answer (score 0):

**To detect if a user is running Android use this code below**

```
from platform import platform

def is_android() -> bool:
    if 'android' in platform():return True
    return False
```

Comment: On my Android `platform.platform()` is `Linux-5.4.134-qgki-g544c77a8a651-aarch64-with-libc`. No `android` in the string.